# Bundler 1.0.21 & Ruby 1.9.3 -- "$ bundle config" |-> returns "invalid byte sequence in UTF-8 (ArgumentError)"

Tags: ruby, macos, utf-8, rake, bundler

I'm quite new at all of this stuff, so I may have made some simple (and/or horribly disastrous) mistakes. In what follows, I describe the web of issues I'm confronting, but I get the impression that the "bundle config" error is at the root. Here's what I've been facing:

I've been trying to set up a personal wiki with Wagn's interesting arrangement.  I've been trying to [install version 1.8 according to the instructions](http://www.wagn.org/wagn/installation_1.8), but I have been for more than a week on the 3rd step, "Configure", which instructs me to run this bundle command:

```
$ bundle exec rake wagn:install
```

I'm running OS X 10.6.8, MySQL  Ver 14.14 Distrib 5.5.20, Ruby 1.9.3, Rails 2.3.11, Bundler 1.0.21, and Rake 0.9.2.2 (think that's everything relevant).

Initially, I was getting this error:

```
rake/rdoctask is deprecated. Use rdoc/task instead (in RDoc 2.4.2+)
```

which I (hopefully) overcame by making the [repairs suggested by Matthew Mceachen](http://matthew.mceachen.us/blog/howto-fix-rake-rdoctask-is-deprecated-use-rdoc-task-instead-1169.html).

I have now been stumped on the following error, which is returned when I try to run the above cited "bundle exec rake" command (user name replaced with 'ME'):

```
xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx:wagn xxxxxxxxx$ bundle exec rake wagn:install
/Users/ME/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p0@global/gems/bundler-1.0.21/lib/bundler/settings.rb:11:in `[]': undefined method `[]' for false:FalseClass (NoMethodError)
    from /Users/ME/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p0@global/gems/bundler-1.0.21/lib/bundler.rb:261:in `configure_gem_home_and_path'
    from /Users/ME/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p0@global/gems/bundler-1.0.21/lib/bundler.rb:82:in `configure'
    from /Users/ME/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p0@global/gems/bundler-1.0.21/lib/bundler.rb:136:in `definition'
    from /Users/ME/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p0@global/gems/bundler-1.0.21/lib/bundler.rb:126:in `load'
    from /Users/ME/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p0@global/gems/bundler-1.0.21/lib/bundler.rb:110:in `setup'
    from /Users/ME/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p0@global/gems/bundler-1.0.21/lib/bundler/cli.rb:340:in `exec'
    from /Users/ME/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p0@global/gems/bundler-1.0.21/lib/bundler/vendor/thor/task.rb:22:in `run'
    from /Users/ME/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p0@global/gems/bundler-1.0.21/lib/bundler/vendor/thor/invocation.rb:118:in `invoke_task'
    from /Users/ME/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p0@global/gems/bundler-1.0.21/lib/bundler/vendor/thor.rb:263:in `dispatch'
    from /Users/ME/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p0@global/gems/bundler-1.0.21/lib/bundler/vendor/thor/base.rb:386:in `start'
    from /Users/ME/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p0@global/gems/bundler-1.0.21/bin/bundle:13:in `<top (required)>'
    from /Users/ME/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p0/bin/bundle:19:in `load'
    from /Users/ME/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p0/bin/bundle:19:in `<main>'
```

I've tried to check this against the bundler configurations, but receive the following error when I use "$ bundle config":

```
XXXXXXXXXXXXX:wagn XXXXXXXXX$ bundle config
Settings are listed in order of priority. The top value will be used.

    /Users/ME/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p0@global/gems/bundler-1.0.21/lib/bundler/settings.rb:27:in `block in all': invalid byte sequence in UTF-8 (ArgumentError)
        from /Users/ME/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p0@global/gems/bundler-1.0.21/lib/bundler/settings.rb:27:in `select'
        from /Users/ME/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p0@global/gems/bundler-1.0.21/lib/bundler/settings.rb:27:in `all'
        from /Users/ME/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p0@global/gems/bundler-1.0.21/lib/bundler/cli.rb:375:in `config'
        from /Users/ME/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p0@global/gems/bundler-1.0.21/lib/bundler/vendor/thor/task.rb:22:in `run'
        from /Users/ME/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p0@global/gems/bundler-1.0.21/lib/bundler/vendor/thor/invocation.rb:118:in `invoke_task'
        from /Users/ME/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p0@global/gems/bundler-1.0.21/lib/bundler/vendor/thor.rb:263:in `dispatch'
        from /Users/ME/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p0@global/gems/bundler-1.0.21/lib/bundler/vendor/thor/base.rb:386:in `start'
        from /Users/ME/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p0@global/gems/bundler-1.0.21/bin/bundle:13:in `<top (required)>'
        from /Users/ME/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p0/bin/bundle:19:in `load'
        from /Users/ME/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p0/bin/bundle:19:in `<main>'
```

Tho I've found several discussions dealing with erros citing "invalid byte sequences", none of them seem to apply to my situation in any clear way.  The most common response seemed to be to check and the locale and make sure everything is assigned to UTF-8, which I did.  $ locale now returns this:

```
LANG="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_COLLATE="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_CTYPE="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_MESSAGES="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_MONETARY="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_NUMERIC="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_TIME="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_ALL=
```

My gem list, for good measure:

```
actionmailer (3.2.1, 2.3.11)
actionpack (3.2.1, 2.3.11)
activemodel (3.2.1)
activerecord (3.2.1, 2.3.11)
activeresource (3.2.1, 2.3.11)
activesupport (3.2.1, 2.3.11)
arel (3.0.0)
aws-s3 (0.6.2)
builder (3.0.0)
bundler (1.0.21 ruby)
erubis (2.7.0)
hike (1.2.1)
hoptoad_notifier (2.4.11)
htmlentities (4.2.4)
i18n (0.6.0)
image_science (1.2.1)
journey (1.0.1)
json (1.6.5, 1.4.6)
macaddr (1.0.0)
mail (2.4.1)
mime-types (1.17.2, 1.16)
multi_json (1.0.4)
mysql (2.8.1)
newrelic_rpm (3.3.1, 3.1.0)
polyglot (0.3.3)
rack (1.4.1, 1.1.3, 1.1.2)
rack-cache (1.1)
rack-ssl (1.3.2)
rack-test (0.6.1)
rails (3.2.1, 2.3.11)
railties (3.2.1)
rake (0.9.2.2, 0.9.2)
rdoc (3.12)
ruby-mysql (2.9.4)
RubyInline (3.8.6)
spork (0.9.0)
sprockets (2.1.2)
thor (0.14.6)
tilt (1.3.3)
treetop (1.4.10)
tzinfo (0.3.31)
uuid (2.2.0)
xml-simple (1.1.1, 1.1.0)
ZenTest (4.6.2, 4.5.0)
```

Any insight you might be able to provide would be very helpful.  Even if I seem to be pointed in the completely wrong direction or whatever, a few words to point me aright would be gratefully received.  Thanks in advance!

Comment: I know this is old, but just in case. Have you tried saving the files in UTF-8?